# how to solve it: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883

Tags: node.js, windows, graphql

Hi I have an error trying to run yarn dev (node ./index.js)
[image]
any ideas to solve? maybe I need to install something?
my package.json is but I don't know why it doesn't execute

```
{
   "name": "instaclone",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "The Instaclone app server",
   "main": "index.js",
   "author": "Cesaru",
   "license": "MIT",
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "node ./index.js"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "apollo-server": "^ 2.19.0",
     "dotenv": "^ 8.2.0",
     "graphql": "^ 15.4.0",
     "mongoose": "^ 5.11.3"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing `node_modules` folder and run `yarn install` again